# Time series forecasting for dataset spanning a week

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, lstm

I am a newbie in time series data forecasting. I have a week long data and the counts represent arrivals per 5 mins period. A part of the dataset is shown below.

```
DATE               COUNT       
2018-06-01 10:00:00   4922
2018-06-01 10:05:00   7924
2018-06-01 10:10:00   8352
2018-06-01 10:15:00   7865
2018-06-01 10:20:00   5642
```

I am trying to model it to forecast data for the next day. I tried SARIMA model in Python using the following code to model it since it clearly has a seasonal component to it but the results are not good as shown.

```
train, test = train_test_split(data, train_size=1600)
arima_model = auto_arima(train, seasonal=True, m=7)
prediction = pd.DataFrame(arima_model.predict(n_periods = 416),index=test.index)
```

[image]

Do you have any recommendations on what other approaches may work best for this data? Since my data does not contain multiple seasonalities, do you think `bats` or `tbats` would be suitable for it? SARIMA may not be working since my dataset is pretty small and does not span months or years plus I am not entirely sure that about the value of `m` in my code.

Comment: `m` is the *length* of a seasonal period, not the *number* of seasonal periods..   For five minute intervals over a day, `m = 288`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [jbowman writes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/601938/time-series-forecasting-for-dataset-spanning-a-week#comment1115633_601938), `m` gives the number of buckets in each season. You have $24\times \frac{60}{5}=288$ 5-minute buckets in a 24-hour day, so if you want to model day-over-day seasonality, you need to set `m=288`. However, you might also have week-over-week seasonality, and there are $7\times 24\times \frac{60}{5}=2016$ such buckets in a week, so to capture this seasonality, you would need to set `m=2016`. You can use [seasonal plots](https://otexts.com/fpp3/seasonal-plots.html) and [seasonal subseries plots](https://otexts.com/fpp3/subseries.html) to investigate the strength of a seasonality.

However, this will likely hand you another problem: [ARIMA does not handle long seasonality well.](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/longseasonality/) I don't know about the Python implementation, but I would expect it to break down for weekly seasonality. I would recommend an STL decomposition instead.

If you get more than one week's worth of data, you will almost certainly see [multiple-seasonalities](/questions/tagged/multiple-seasonalities), with daily patterns different between weekdays and weekends. You could take a look at the course of arrivals over each day separately, possibly smoothed, and look whether the plots look like [this one](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3107/1352).

There are specialized methods for such situations. [The tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/multiple-seasonalities/info) has pointers to them, but most are only implemented in R packages. You could try implementing them in Python, or switch to R for this analysis.